# product of two multiline textboxes and display it also to another multiline textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox, multiplication, multiline

I want to know how to perform calculations such as multiplication of two multiline textboxes and the product of it will also display in a multiline textbox.
*Please see the design below*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS6J2.png)

Comment: Split your inputs on newline, iterate over the arrays and multiply the parsed decimal value of the left array with that of the right, putting the final amount in a string list. Then join the string list with a newline and put it in the third textbox.

Comment: Unless you have a project-scope to do it this way, you should try the `DataGridView` control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the multiplication of two multiline textboxes and display the result in a multiline textbox, you can use the following code：

```
private void textBox2_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float a, b;
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Lines.Length ; i++)
        {

            float.TryParse(textBox1.Lines[i], out a);
            float.TryParse(textBox2.Lines[i], out b);
            textBox3.AppendText((a * b).ToString()+ Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

And you have to add an EventHandler in Form1.Designer.cs file:

```
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 
        this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(312, 110);
        this.textBox2.Multiline = true;
        this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
        this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 167);
        this.textBox2.TabIndex = 4;
        this.textBox2.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox2_LostFocus);
```

[image]